# Substituting `find_if` function

Tags: algorithm, stl, c++

I wrote a class method using STL `find_if`. The code is the following:

```
void
Simulator::CommunicateEvent (pEvent e)
{
  pwEvent we (e);
  std::list<pEvent> l;

  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_simulatorObjects.size (); i++)
  {
    l = m_simulatorObjects[i]->ProcessEvent (we);
    // no action needed if list is empty
    if (l.empty ())
      continue;
    // sorting needed if list comprises 2+ events
    if (l.size () != 1)
      l.sort (Event::Compare);

    std::list<pEvent>::iterator it = m_eventList.begin ();
    std::list<pEvent>::iterator jt;
    for (std::list<pEvent>::iterator returnedElementIt = l.begin ();
         returnedElementIt != l.end ();
         returnedElementIt++)
    {
      // loop through the array until you find an element whose time is just
      // greater than the time of the element we want to insert
      Simulator::m_eventTime = (*returnedElementIt)->GetTime ();
      jt = find_if (it,
                    m_eventList.end (),
                    IsJustGreater);
      m_eventList.insert (jt, *returnedElementIt);
      it = jt;
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I later discovered that the machine that will run the code is equipped with the libstdc++ library version 4.1.1-21, which apparently is lacking `find_if`. Needless to say, I cannot upgrade the library, nor can I ask someone to do it.

When compiling, the error I get is:

```
simulator.cc: In member function ‘void sim::Simulator::CommunicateEvent(sim::pEvent)’:
simulator.cc:168: error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<sim::Event> >&, std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<sim::Event> >, sim::Simulator::<anonymous struct>&)’
simulator.cc: In static member function ‘static void sim::Simulator::InsertEvent(sim::pEvent)’:
simulator.cc:191: error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<sim::Event> >&, std::_List_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<sim::Event> >, sim::Simulator::<anonymous struct>&)’
make: *** [simulator.o] Error 1
```

How can I solve the problem?

I thought I could define a `find_if` function as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/). However, I have some concerns:

1. What about performance? The function that makes use of find_if needs to be as efficient as possible.
2. How can I do conditional compilation? I couldn't find a macro telling the version of the libstdc++ installed.

What are your thoughts about it?
TIA,
Jir

## References

Source files: [simulator.h](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/lte_sim/file/db0e0eb1f23d/src/simulator.h) and [simulator.cc](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/lte_sim/file/db0e0eb1f23d/src/simulator.cc)

## Solution

Defined `IsJustGreater` outside the `Simulator` class and declared `IsJustGreater_s` friend of `Simulator`:

```
struct IsJustGreater_s : public std::unary_function<const pEvent, bool> {
  inline bool operator() (const pEvent e1) {return (e1->GetTime () > Simulator::m_eventTime);}
} IsJustGreater;
```

Called `IsJustGreater` in `find_if` this way:
      jt = find_if (it, m_eventList.end (), sim::IsJustGreater);

Comment: IIRC find_if is not in the C++ standard, only in the C++0x draft.

Comment: @Alexandre C: `find_if` is in C++98, You're probably thinking about `copy_if`

Comment: Could you post a sample program that isn't compiling for you?  `std::find_if` should be in 4.1.1, given that it isn't exactly a new template.

Comment: @Dave I think you're right. I've just `grep`'d `/usr/include/c++/4.1/` and there are reference to `find_if`. I've just edited the post with both the definition of the method using `find_if` and the error I get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error, it appears that you're attempting to use an anonymous type as the argument.  I do not believe anonymous types are allowed to be template arguments.

From the error, I believe you have something like this:

```
class Simulator {
    struct {
       bool operator(const pEvent& p) { ... } ;
    } IsJustGreater;
}
```

what you want is to give it a name and then change the find_if to instantiate the class (see below)

```
class Simulator {
    // class is now an inner named-class
    struct IsJustGreater {
        bool operator(const pEvent& p) { ... } ;
    };
}


// This is how you use the class
jt = std::find_if(it, m_eventList.end(), IsJustGreater() );
```

Comment: Good news. The compiler complains about an `invalid use of ‘struct sim::Simulator::IsJustGreater’` just in one of the two functions using `find_if` --- the static one. Now I am wondering how I can make such struct static.

Comment: Are you sure you're not still trying to use the class member vs. just instantiating a new IsJustGreater()?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that a function using `find_if` is a normal member function, whereas the other is declared as static. I guess the problem is due to that.

Comment: Are you declaring IsJustGreater as a member variable of the Simulator?  If so, you could declare it static to allow its use in the static function as well.  If it has no data, you can also just create the instance as a temporary object when you call find_if, and not have it exist as a member at all.

Comment: That's a good idea. Basically it's a struct that inherits from `std::unary_function<const pEvent, bool>` and that has the operator `()` overloaded. I'll try and do that.

Comment: Okay, here's the solution. I declared `IsJustGreater` as a static struct outside the `Simualtor` class, but friend of it (so it can access private members). I've edited the question to reflect the changes. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're using the `std::` qualifier before `std::list` but not `std::find_if`. Try putting the `std::` in front so that the compiler can find it within the namespace.

Comment: I think ADL should pick up the namespace from the arguments.